# Excel/RibbonUI menu disabled

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

**Note** The following problem was solved by creating a new workbook copying all the data, macros and other code across. Any insight into what causes a workbook to "break" would be welcome!

I have an excel file with a custom ribbonui. I've recently added a new group with a new menu, it (was) copied from the first group and certain items were removed.

The first group "library" and all its controls work as expected. The "documentmenu" menu in the "document" group however is grayed out and I cannot figure out why!

I've tried adding in a `getEnabled` and plain `enabled` attribute to the menu but it wont fire, neither will any of the `getEnabled` events for the menu's contained buttons.

When I open the ribbon for the first time the `getLabel` event does fire and sets the label correctly.

I've tried re-naming the group and all the controls to something without "document" in-case it's conflicting somehow, but again no go.

Does anyone know what might be causing this to happen?

Below is the entire customui xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI 
    onLoad="CustomUI.Ribbon_onLoad" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab 
          id="Main" 
          label="Initech">
        <group
            id="Library"
            label="Library"
            tag="Library"
            centerVertically="true">
          <menu
              id="LibraryMenu"
              tag="Library"
              image="gear"
              getLabel="CustomUI.Menu_getLabel">
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_Open"
                tag="Library"
                label="Open Library"
                imageMso="FileOpen"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_New"
                tag="Library"
                label="New Library"
                imageMso="FileNew"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <menuSeparator
                id="LibraryMenu_Separator0" />
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_Save"
                tag="Library"
                label="Save"
                imageMso="FileSave"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_Close"
                tag="Library"
                label="Close"
                imageMso="FileClose"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_Default"
                tag="Library"
                label="Set as Default"
                imageMso="AcceptInvitation"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <menuSeparator
                id="LibraryMenu_Separator1" />
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_Add"
                tag="Library"
                label="Add Component"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <button
                id="LibraryMenu_Editor"
                tag="Library"
                label="Edit Menu"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
          </menu>
          <dynamicMenu
              id="LibraryComponents"
              tag="Library"
              image="book_stack"
              getLabel="CustomUI.Menu_getLabel"
              getEnabled="CustomUI.Menu_getEnabled"
              getContent="CustomUI.Menu_getContent" />
        </group>
        <group
            id="Document"
            label="Document"
            tag="Document"
            centerVertically="true">
          <menu
              id="DocumentMenu"
              tag="Document"
              imageMso="FileOpen"
              getLabel="CustomUI.Menu_getLabel">
            <button
                id="DocumentMenu_Open"
                tag="Document"
                label="Open Document"
                imageMso="FileOpen"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <button
                id="DocumentMenu_New"
                tag="Document"
                label="New Document"
                imageMso="FileNew"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <menuSeparator
                id="DocumentMenu_Separator0" />
            <button
                id="DocumentMenu_Save"
                tag="Document"
                label="Save"
                imageMso="FileSave"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
            <button
                id="DocumentMenu_Close"
                tag="Document"
                label="Close"
                imageMso="FileClose"
                getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"
                onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction" />
          </menu>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**Update** after hours of playing about trying to figure out whats going on, turns out my workbook is damaged some how. The code works fine if I put it into a new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

1. centerVertically is not a valid property.
   Kindly refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd921026%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
2. getEnabled="CustomUI.Button_getEnabled"  &  onAction="CustomUI.Button_onAction"
   Avoid **period .** in name of callback function as we cannot define a sub/function   like CustomUI.Button_getEnabled.

3 when using getEnabled attribute for a button a callback function is to be called when the application needs to determine the enabled state of the button.

[sample code - getEnabled for ribbion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/220815a2-0ccf-4ee3-b6e4-f2a33e5563df/)

Comment: centreVertically is a valid group attribute in the customui.14 schema http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.office2010.customui.group.centervertically.aspx and the period in my subs does work, it allows me to specify the module name where the sub resides. (this might be specific to VBA).